# Smalltalk seaside #call: rendering a blank page

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

So I have a seaside application. The first component just render a subcomponent:

```
MCRootComponent>>initialize
 super initialize.
 self main: MCMainComponent new.
MCRootComponent>>renderComponentOn:html
 renderContentOn: html
 html render: main
```

Now the subcomponent being rendered looks like:

```
MCMainComponent>>renderContentOn: html
 html tbsForm:[
  html tbsContainerFluid: [ 
   html anchor
     callback:  [  self call: (MCServiceOrderComponent from: MCServiceOrder new)];
     with: 'New Service Order' ]]
```

and the MCServiceOrderComponent:

```
MCServiceOrderComponent>>initialize
super initialize.   
customerComponent := MCClienteComponent new.
vehicleComponent := MCVehicleComponent new.
vehicleComponent lookupCallback: [
    self show:(MCVehicleLookupComponent new) onAnswer:[:vehicle|    
    vehicle ifNotNil: [ 
        serviceOrder vehicle: vehicle.
        vehicleComponent objectToRender: vehicle.
        customerComponent objectToRender: vehicle customer ]]]

MCServiceOrderComponent>>renderContentOn: html
html heading level1 with: 'ServiceOrder'.   
html tbsForm with: [ 
    html render: vehicleComponent.
    html render: customerComponent.     
]
```

So far this renders allright. Notice the lookup callback being passed to the MCVehicleComponent. This block is passed to the callback on a button rendered inside the MCVehicleComponent.

```
MCVehicleComponent>>renderContentOn: html
    self renderContainer: 'Vehicle' on: html  with:  [      
        self renderSearchFor: #id on: html with: self lookupCallback.                
        self renderInputFor: #maker on: html.
        self renderInputFor: #model on: html.       
        self renderInputFor: #color on: html ]

MCVehicleComponent>>renderSearchFor: aSymbol on: html with: aBlock
html tbsFormGroup: [ 
       html label: aSymbol asCapitalizedPhrase.
        html tbsInputGroup: [ 
               html textInput tbsFormControl on: aSymbol of: self objectToRender.                   
                        html tbsInputGroupButton: [
                            html tbsButton callback: aBlock;                    
                            with: [ html tbsGlyphIcon iconSearch ] ] ]]
```

It should #call: to a MCVehicleLookupComponent and return the result back. However the reality is that as soon as the #call: it's made, the page content goes blank. I have tried calling the MCVehicleLookupComponent directly from the MCMainComponent and it works fine, so I know the problem isn't there. Do you have any idea what could be causing this behavior?

I'm fairly new at smalltalk so please be patient with the stupid questions and horrible code (this is my first application. Any suggestions are welcome).

Comment: What "approach mentioned above"? Please be more specific. Also post some code if you can.

Comment: @MaxLeske I edited the question as suggested. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Much better :). What version of Seaside are you using? What is the `tbs` prefix? (I'm not very familiar with the newer additions). I don't see the render code for the `MCVehicleLookupComponent`, but I assume that's fine, as you say. Put a halt in the block passed to `#lookupCallback:` and see if it gets triggered.

Comment: you were right. I was just calling the wrong component. Thanks for the support though.

Comment: tbs stands for twitter bootstrap btw

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling out the wrong component. Everything works as a charm. Sorry.